# Visual studio: Making a web app using SQL Server

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

To be specific
I have a local server running on my pc called MySQLServer57
and I'm running it on MySQL Workbench

i want to know: What tutorials can i follow or find that will show me how to extract information from the database like tables, values etc and use them and display them on the web app coded in c#. etc :)

Comment: This isnt on-topic for this [**forum**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and Too Broad. Just google, how connect to a db, how create a web page c#.

Comment: I have, they are not specific to what i desire. I can literally see the database in my visual studio, i just need to know how to exploit it. any links to tutorial videos would be great

Comment: Try this [channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/kudvenkat) have tutorial about lot of technologies. Check speciially the [MVC](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v) section, But you also may need Javascript, Jquery and AngularJS.

Comment: btw you should change the title because SQL server is the Microsoft DB, but looks like you are talking about MySql